# getBSSID() in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi

I am trying to get BSSID of WiFi but i am always getting 02:00:00:00:00:00 . How to get the Wifi MAC address ?

In android Manifest -

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Code

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
Toast.makeText(UserDashboardActivity.this,"macAddress " + wifiInfo.getBSSID(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same problem. As far as I know using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` permission requires also permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`. Also make sure to check if Settings -> Location is turned on in your mobile device settings, and that location permission is granted in App settings.

Last hope is to check ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in runtime.